# Do I understand the phrase "due time pal" correctly?

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context, sentence

I thanked someone really important for following me on Instagram.

his reply: due time pal

Does it mean that it was time to do so?

thanks

Comment: It sounds to me like the person thought that it was due time (past time, or a bit late) that they had begun to follow you.

Answer (score 0):

I think so. Actually, that it was long overdue; past due time to do so. It's hard to be certain though, not knowing more. They COULD be saying "all in due time, pal" but that doesn't really make sense here. Hope this helps.

Comment: Or they could be saying that the thanks for following were overdue.

Comment: @jwpat7 that's a pretty obnoxious thing for the person to say, in response to a thank-you message. Of course, the quality of humans purveying themselves on Instagram is questionable, and certainly this sort of attitude is present.

Comment: jwpat7, it definitely wasn't that haha.

@Ron Kyle, Thanks, makes sense now.